# Gracemonkey/Tampermonkey. Как использовать div id для отображения его в блоке

Tags: javascript

Есть множество конструкций на сайте типа:

```
<div id="dhfpaiogi4ofpsddfg069843534d532345" class="same">
<div class="other">
внутри куча контента
…
</div>
</div>
```

Нужно взять последние N символов из id блока с классом «same» и вставить в блок «other» текстом. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите, какой код у вас уже есть и с чем конкретно проблемы.

Comment: В том то и дело, что с js знаком только поверхностно и не знаю с какой стороны подойти, как забрать N символов из id. Пока дальше _var div =  document.getElementsByClassName(same);_ я не продвинулся.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('other')[0].innerHTML = document.getElementsByClassName('same')[0].id;
```